# PHP cannot select database even though connected

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Just installed MAMP and am learning about php and connecting to my databases. I seem to be able to connect to mysql but can't connect or see any databases in phpMyAdmin.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root'; 
$db = 'test';
$host = 'localhost';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password);

//newly editied
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($db, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
   echo "did not connect";
}
?>
```

When I run it, I'll get the words "good", so I know I'm connecting, followed by "did not connect", so it's not connecting to my database.

I've also tried adding this code and nothing gets echoed at all even though I have several databases created.

```
$res = mysqli_query("SHOW DATABASES");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $row['Database'] . "\n";
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong when checking the connection status.

You use:

```
if ($link) {
    echo "good";
}
```

And should use:

```
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

As per the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), `mysqli_connect()` will always return an object, so it will never be `false`.

You also inverted parameters `$db` and `$link` on DB selection, and used an improper function in consideration of your previous code. It should be

```
$mysqli->select_db($db)
```

And not:

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($db, $link);
```

which in correct order is in fact:

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, $db);
```

Read the `mysqli_select_db()` [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) for more details on proper use.

Comment: Just changed my code, thanks. But there doesn't seem to be an error with connecting to mysqli... I still can't connect to any databases. Or show any of them, for that matter. Any ideas?